# JSP deploy problem in jboss

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jboss, mod-jk

I have Jboss 4.0.4GA setup in Linux. after I start my jboss without problem, I tried to access JSP page in browser, got error:

> ```
> The XML page cannot be displayed 
> Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error
> ```
>
> and then click the Refresh button, or
>   try again later.
>
> ---
>
> A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'https://uappdev.marvell.com/login/index.jsp'. Lin...
>
> <%@ page import="com.marvell.macroip.util.Constants" %>
>       -^

and I find out the converted servlets class files is not in [jboss home]/work/jboss.web/localhost/_/org... directory. No errors in Jboss log file.

Can anybody help me to resolve this problem? I already spend a lot time one this problem, but no luck.

here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.marvell.macroip.web.util.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/extract/*</url-pattern>    
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>    
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.marvell.macroip.web.util.PublicSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.marvell.macroip.web.ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>validate</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=400</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=401</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=403</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=404</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=405</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>408</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=408</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>410</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=410</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>411</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=411</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>412</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=412</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>413</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=413</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>414</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=414</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>415</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=415</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>501</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=501</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>502</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=502</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=503</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>506</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.jsp?code=506</location>
  </error-page>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/for-loop.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/for-loop.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/root.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/root.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>MacroIP Login</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>MacroIP Login</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Extract</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Extract</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/extract/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

jsp page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page import="com.marvell.macroip.util.Constants" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/logic-ext.tld" prefix="logic-ext" %>
<bean:parameter id="logout" name="logout" value="false"/>

<html>
<head>
<title>Tracking System</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="/includes/imgChange.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="/includes/css_bCheck.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/includes/sifr.js">// flash insert code</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#eeeeee" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
              <table width="470" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   <tr valign="middle">
<td align="right" bgcolor="#ebebeb" class="smallgrey"><span class="red">*</span>User Name &nbsp;</td>
                   <td>
<html:text property="userName" styleClass="formElement" size="29" disabled="false" style="width:290px"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="middle">
                  <td align="right" bgcolor="#ebebeb" class="smallgrey"><span class="red">*</span>Password&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>
                  <html:password property="password" maxlength="35" redisplay="false" styleClass="formElement" size="29" disabled="false" style="width:290px"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                <tr>
                  <td align="right">
                    <input type="image" alt="Submit" border="0" />
                  </td>                        
                </tr>
              </table>
```

if i try this jsp page, it will be blank page or display the original jsp code in browser.

```
   <html><head><title>JSP Test</title> 
   <%! 
   String message = "Hello, World."; 
   %> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <h2><%= message%></h2> 
   <%= new java.util.Date() %> 
   </body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a jdk installed so that JBoss can compile JSPs? (not sure this is the cause though)

Comment: Tomcat + JBoss don't use javac to compile JSPs any more, they do that internally

Comment: Ah yes, right, JBoss bundles Tomcat 5.5. I wrongly assumed it was Tomcat 5.0. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I did install jdk 1.5 as java_home. dont know why jboss can not compile JSPs

Comment: Jboss is serving up your JSP "as is", directly to your browser. The browser is trying to interpret it as XML (for its own reasons), but somewhere you have configured JBoss not to treat this file as a JSP. Can you post your `web.xml`, as well as the JSP page source?

Comment: i have added the web.xml and jsp page

Comment: Why are you returning an XML instead of plain simple HTML ?

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit?

Comment: I dont know why it doesn't recognize the tag. the URL I am trying to hit is my company's server url. only allow to access within company's network. but it's a very simple login page called index.jsp.  I did setup mod_jk.conf and mod_jk.so to connect jboss and apache.

Comment: @menmenger - Yeah, I figured it was internal... I was just wondering if perhaps the apache->jboss process (or something else) isn't actually hitting the page that you think it is.  Eg, you'd see a problem like this if apache were serving the page itself (misconfigured apache) instead of redirecting to jboss.  Or possibly if you were hitting something other than a .jsp (some other permutation of the url).

Comment: Is it jboss 4.0.4ga can't use together with jdk 1.5?

Comment: @jsight - you got a point there. I guess it still might be apache problem, any suggestion about how to look for the solution? thank you!

Comment: @mengmenger - I don't know enough apache to guess that unfortunately.  I would suggest looking at apache http access logs and jboss access logs at the same time while hitting the site.  If you aren't seeing the hits (or seeing them on different urls than you'd expect) in the jboss logs, you'd be a lot closer to a solution.  It'd be really unusual for jboss to simply not compile the page and spit up the raw src due to a config issue, imo.

Comment: @jsight - thank you very much for your tips though! I solve the problem. I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I did find out the solution. from what jsight said "Yeah, I figured it was internal... I was just wondering if perhaps the apache->jboss process (or something else) isn't actually hitting the page that you think it is. Eg, you'd see a problem like this if apache were serving the page itself (misconfigured apache) instead of redirecting to jboss. Or possibly if you were hitting something other than a .jsp (some other permutation of the url). – jsight"

I found out it should be apache+ssl trying to resolve jsp by itself instead passing jsp request to jboss. and then my coworker and I find out the mod_jk is not loaded properly in apache. therefore, add "JkMountCopy ALL" right after the mod-jk.conf loaded in httpd.conf file. and restart Apache, voila.... it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here that JSP's are not compiled nor executed as expected.

The one who's responsible for that is the `JspServlet` which is configured in the `web.xml` of the servlet container. In case of JBoss AS, that's Tomcat and its `web.xml` is by default located in the `/conf` folder of the Tomcat installation. It **must** contain an active (i.e. not outcommented) `<servlet>` definition of the `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` and a `<servlet-mapping>` on the same `servlet-name` along with an `url-pattern` of `*.jsp`. Verify if anything is right.

Another cause might have been that the `web.xml` of the webapplication itself (the one in the `/WEB-INF` folder) has another `Filter` or `Servlet` on exactly the same `url-pattern` as the `JspServlet` (and is thus overriding it), but that's not the case after judging the `web.xml` you posted.

Comment: Thank you! I did find out there is a place in ｊｂｏｓｓｗｅｂ－ｔｏｍｃａｔ５５．ｓａｒ／ｃｏｎｆ/web.xml says "uncomment to use jdk1.5", I　ｕｎｃｏｍｍｅｎｔ　ｉｔ　ｓｉｎｃｅ　Ｉam using jdk 1.5.0_16. But still have the same problem after I restart jboss. Is it jboss 4.0.4ga can't use together with jdk 1.5?

Comment: I also checked the <servlet> definition of the org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet and along with url-pattern of *.jsp. it's all there.